# Ajax POST Success But No Data Are Send

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have problem to upload multi file using ajax, in this case im using codeingiter, when I call $_POST array return null on upload function, this is my my form I'm using this snippets

**Form**

https://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/2nzL9f7g/

**Server Test**

```
public function test_upload()
{

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

**Return**

```
Array
(
)
```

My question is how to fix this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of `$_POST` use `$_FILES` to access the file input

Comment: @pradeep yes its work....thanks , but how to show or call the multiple file send in $_FILES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$_FILES`

```
public function test_upload()
{

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

*Your input file must have name array for multiple files like this :*

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

for more :http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Works, thanks for help, but files only one in pre tag..how to get all sending data ?

Comment: use name as an array like this  `name="files[]"` for multiple file, see my updated answer

Comment: by the way if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green and do upvote also